# Unmanned guard boat

Tags: simulation, simulator, usv

I need an urgent help in my graduation project on unmanned guard boat. 
I need to control the boat autonomously and manually using ArduPilot and Arduino Uno.

I just ask if anyone has the code, that can be written on the ArduPilot, that enables control both:

- autonomously, using way-points, and;
- manually, using LabVIEW,

and then sends the data through the Arduino to complete the movement of the boat as the motors are connected to the Arduino.

Furthermore I need to know to send GPS coordinates using a U-blox NEO-7M connected to ArduPilot running on an Arduino to be displayed through the serial port of PC on the software.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Sarah, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question.

Comment: Is it a U-blox NEO-7M or EVA-7M?